# Nautilus using lots of memory

Tags: nautilus, memory-usage

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.1 and yesterday and today I've noticed that Nautilus is using a lot of memory (see picture). Has anyone else been noticing this kind of memory usage or should I report a bug somewhere?

[image]

Comment: Memory use of nautilus probably will also depend on the number of windows/the size of the folders/etc that you have currently open. Your question will be complete only if you also report how heavily you are currently using nautilus.

Comment: Also running 18.04.1, and I could bump memory usage up to 380 MB after opening up to 12 windows with several searches, so rather heavy use. When closing all windows except one, the memory is not being released. Closing the last windows closes the nautilus process and releases all memory. So indeed you may go into this high usage after long use,where at least one window remained open throughout.